# Making this password search more intelligent

Tags: security, homework, bash, openssl

In a homework, there is an exercise in which I have a script that is used to search for a password.

One of the questions is if is possible to make it "more intelligent", and I'm stuck on it.

```
#!/bin/bash

space1="a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"

if [  $# -le 1 ]
then 
    echo "Ussage: " $0 SALT PASSWORD_CODED
    exit
fi

for i in $space1
do
for j in $space1
do
for k in $space1
do

    variable=$(openssl passwd -crypt -salt "$1" "$i$j$k")
    if [ "$variable" = $2 ]
        then
        echo password found: $i$j$k
        exit
    fi
done
done
done
```

If it is possible, I prefer only a clue to help me to discover the answer correct, not the answer itself. I promise to post the result when I get the answer for myself.

Comment: As suggested, you could use common words first or a dictionary, but brute force is brute force. In this case it's only 3 lower case characters, so it should take no time at all. I don't know if there is any other way to make the algorithm more intelligent.

Comment: What does "more intelligent" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real way to speed up the brute-force enumeration of all possible 3-letter passwords.

Perhaps you could use the dictionary.  There's a finite list of 3-letter English words.    They may be slightly more common.

Also, if you google for  "most common passwords", some kind of 3-letter version of that list could be tried before anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the man page for openssl http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html

It is the command being executed here:

```
$(openssl passwd -crypt -salt "$1" "$i$j$k")
```

Another Clue below.
Only roll your curser over it if you need the extra help.

> Do you need to pass the passwords one at a time.

Still have not worked it out!

> Try: openssl passwd -crypt -salt <salt> <passwd1> <password2> <password3> ....

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do

```
space1="a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
for i in $space1; do
    for j in $space1; do
        for k in $space1; do
            echo $i$j$k
        done
     done
done
```

in bash is probably :

```
for i in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}; do echo $i; done
```

Then, depending on what your homeworks says, it might or might not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support passwords with 4-5-6-n characters without more loops you could write a [bijective function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) which maps [integers to strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#The_bijective_base-26_system).

Maybe you want to check the homepage of the [John the Ripper password cracker](http://www.openwall.com/john/). It has downloadable word lists and maybe you can find some information about how John generates the passwords. Also check the *Methods of attack* chapter in 
[Rob Shimonski's Hacking techniques article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/s-crack/).